# Vertical float switch for tethered float sump pump?

Tags: basement, sump-pump

I have a sump pump in my basement that has a tethered float switch.  The sump is not deep enough for the switch to turn on so I have to go down there and turn it on manually every time it rains hard.  If I put a vertical float switch with a piggyback plug/switch will it turn on the sump pump?

Answer (score 1):

Try this fix, shorten the tether so the float will turn on/off quicker, or replace the pump with a one that has a vertical mounted float switch. I got rid of my tethered float switch pumps for ones with the vertical switch. They work great with just a short rise in water level.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you secure the original float in the 'on' position and it doesn't experience corrosion due to its newly stationary duty. I'd be concerned about having a second possible point of failure in a system protecting so much value.